# Default image is not displayed while creating a node

Tags: nodes, 6, media

I have created a content type and added a *Preview Image* field. Its type is *file* and its widget type is *image*. For *Default Image*, I have uploaded an image that should be displayed at the time of creating one new node.

My problem is that it is not displaying on the node creation form.

Comment: Why to try FILE type ? There is an Image type in core. If you want to upload an  Image use type = Image instead of a file

Comment: Can you plz tell me where have you seen image type in field_type option.

Comment: Well i cannot post image here look at my answer. Which drupal version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[image: SCreen Shot]
Here is the screen shot for  field type. The drupal version i am using is Drupal 7 .

Comment: I am using drupal 6.

Comment: If it is drupal 6 then You need to install Image module. http://drupal.org/project/image.
Generally if you use fieldtype file and save an image the output will be simply a name of that image you uploaded. 
So if you use fieldtype as Image the output can be formatted as you like (thumbnail,original etc)

Comment: Hi I have installed image module, But still the image field is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a picture to the content creation page by adding HTML  or  to the HELP TEXT of your image field. Go to /admin/structure/types/manage/product-node/fields, click "edit" on the right of the image field, put your HTML in help text. Another, but rather unholy way is to add the HTML code using jQuery .append(). I hope this works for you.